# Dlink DWA-182D wireless adaptor not working with Ubuntu 22.04 (linux kernel 5.19.0-41-generic)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 22.04, d-link

I can't see any wireless adaptor on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 with DLink DWA-182D. From my understanding the hardware seems to be connected (using `lsusb`) but `ifconfig` doesn't show the wireless interface. I am attaching the paste (https://pastebin.com/mp8R7JMB) for my command outputs. Please let me know if I can provide anymore outputs to further debug this problem as I am a bit new to this.

Things I have tried:

1. Install drivers from https://github.com/morrownr/8812au-20210629 and reboot
2. Install drivers from official dlink website (https://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-182) but the installation failed. I don't think it even matters as the website says it only supports linux kernel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct process is:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702.git
cd 88x2bu-20210702
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

You will be prompted to set a password for Secure Boot.

Reboot.

Comment: Thank you, after installing the driver from this repo, I can see the wifi adaptor and networks in my area. However, I can't connect to them and keep getting the error: "Connection Failed: secrets were required but not provided"

I have tried multiple wifi networks including my mobile hotspot and all of them are giving the same error. I am sure the passwords are correct.

Comment: I also tried using `nmcli` for connection but the same error popped up in terminal.
```
$ nmcli con up <WIFI SSID> password <password>
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
```

Comment: After rebooting it a few times, it is working. I am not sure what the problem was in between but I am going to accept this answer.